# Java Spring Boot Jpa. Selection from the custom function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a service with the Jpa r2dbc repository and one method. This method should return a selection from the custom SQL function (not the table). When the application uses that method I have an error.

Repository with method:

```java
public interface VirtualAuthorityRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<VirtualAuthority, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT ... FROM get_valid_virtual_relations(:accountId)")
    Flux<VirtualAuthority> getVirtualAuthority(@NonNull Long accountId);
}
```

Example of get_valid_virtual_relations function

```sql
create function get_valid_virtual_relations(accountid integer)
    returns TABLE(authority_id integer, expire_at timestamp without time zone)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT ...;
END;
```

Error message:

> io.r2dbc.postgresql.QUERY: Executing query: BEGIN READ ONLY
> io.r2dbc.postgresql.PARAM: Bind parameter [0] to: 1
> io.r2dbc.postgresql.QUERY                : Executing query: SELECT * FROM get_valid_virtual_relations($1)
> io.r2dbc.postgresql.QUERY: Executing query: ROLLBACK
> c.f.c.e.BaseGrpcExceptionHandler         : org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: executeMany; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM get_valid_virtual_relations($1)]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there a space between : and accountId, causing BadSqlGrammarException. Try after removing it something like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM get_valid_virtual_relations(:accountId)")
```

PS: I don't have enough reputation to comment, so adding it as answer

Comment: It was a typo in the example. Thank you. In my code I do not have this typo